# How to determine if any row is selected in a listbox

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a list box in my Access form. I need to know if any of the rows in this list box has been selected by the user. Is there any simple Access property or method exists for this purpose? I do not want to loop through the listbox to check if any row's selected property is true, because I am only interested to know if a selection action is done.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A list box has the `ItemsSelected` property which returns a read-only reference to the hidden `ItemsSelected` collection.  And you can ask for the `Count` property of that collection ...

```vb
MsgBox Me.YourListBoxName.ItemsSelected.Count & " items selected"
```

Answer (score 7):

The code

```
If ListBox.ListIndex = -1 then
  MsgBox "Nothing selected"
end if
```

should help...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. but it seems not be working if I select and deselect an item from the list box. the listIndex increases to 1 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me...a mix of both comments before, thank you both

```
If List4.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
  MsgBox "Nothing selected"
```

So if nothing is selected I get the message